# Perl LWP Post With Empty Sequence Response

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I am trying to send a POST request to a REST web-service using the Perl LWP library. I am able to successfully complete the POST request with no errors; however, when I try to get the response content, it returns an empty sequence `[]`. I have sent POST requests to the web-service using the Postman application in Chrome, and it returns the expected response. It seems that this happens only for POST and PUT requests: GET requests return the expected content.

Here is my Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = "http://localhost:53076/api/excel(07375ebd-e21f-4ce4-91d7-49dc2de7ceb1)";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1 );

my $json = JSON->new->utf8->allow_nonref;

my @inputs = ( ( "key" => "A", "Value" => "12" ), ( "key" => "B", "Value" => "12" ) );
my @outputs = ( ( "key" => "A", "Value" => "12" ), ( "key" => "B", "Value" => "12" ) );

my %body;

$body{"Inputs"} = \@inputs;
$body{"Outputs"} = \@outputs;

my $jsonString = $json->encode(\%body);

my $response = $ua->post($url, "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content" => $jsonString);

if ($response->is_success)
{
    print "\n========== REQUEST CONTENT ==========\n";

    print $response->decoded_content(), "\n";

}
else
{
    print "\n========== ERROR ==========\n";
    print "Error: ", $response->status_line(), "\n";
    print $response->headers()->as_string(), "\n";

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should have compared what you sent with your script with what you sent with your browser!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an expression, `()` doesn't do anything except to affect precedence. For example, `4 * ( 5 + 6 )` is different than `4 * 5 + 6`. As such,

```
my @inputs = ( ( key => "A", Value => "12" ), ( key => "B", Value => "12" ) );
```

is just a weird way of writing

```
my @inputs = ( "key", "A", "Value", "12", "key", "B", "Value", "12" );
```

If you want to create a hash and return a reference to it, it's done using `{}`.

```
my @inputs  = ( { key => "A", Value => "12" }, { key => "B", Value => "12" } );
my @outputs = ( { key => "A", Value => "12" }, { key => "B", Value => "12" } );
```

That's basically short for

```
my %anon_i1 = ( key => "A", Value => "12" );
my %anon_i2 = ( key => "B", Value => "12" );
my @inputs = ( \%anon_i1, \%anon_i2 );
my %anon_o1 = ( key => "A", Value => "12" );
my %anon_o2 = ( key => "B", Value => "12" );
my @outputs = ( \%anon_o1, \%anon_o2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips...this actually solved my problem! I guess I wasn't providing the property JSON string to the web service.